# SQL pagination and count for duplicate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, pagination

When I select a query output will shown like below

```
EmpID EmpCode   Empname  Date       ID  ClrID   ClrName   Status
100    EMP01    Raj     31 Jul 2014 2   60      clearance   0
100    EMP01    Raj     31 Jul 2014 3   61      Test2       0
101    EMP02    Jino    10 Aug 2014 4   63      Test3       0
102    EMP03    Reegan  30 Jul 2014 5   68      Test4       1
102    EMP03    Reegan  30 Jul 2014 6   113     Test5       1
102    EMP03    Reegan  30 Jul 2014 7   114     Test6       0
103    EMP04    Rajesh  27 May 2014 8   115     Test7       0
```

**But I want the Output Like Below and pagination**

```
TotalCount  RowNum  RowNumber1 EmpID EmpCode Empname  Date       ID ClrID ClrName   Status
4            1          1       100   EMP01   Raj    31 Jul 2014 2  60    clearance 0
4            1          2       100   EMP01   Raj    31 Jul 2014 3  61    Test2     0
4            2          3       101   EMP02   Jino   10 Aug 2014 4  63    Test3     0
4            3          4       102   EMP03   Reegan 30 Jul 2014 5  68    Test4     1
4            3          5       102   EMP03   Reegan 30 Jul 2014 6  113   Test5     1
4            3          6       102   EMP03   Reegan 30 Jul 2014 7  114   Test6     0
4            4          7       103   EMP04   Rajesh 27 May 2014 8  115   Test7     0
```

Comment: What DB engine do you use?

Comment: Whats the TotalCount stands for? And Rownum? You should explain better your question.

Comment: Microsoft SQL server and TotalCount mean how many of the rows comes without duplicate EmpID value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Use dense_rank() and row_number() methods to get this output.
I think you need this output for dynamic table creation.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in some databases using windows/analytic functions:

```
select count(distinct empid) over () as TotalCount,
       dense_rank() over (order by empid) as RowNumber,
       row_number() over (order by empid) as RowNumber1,
       t.*
from table t;
```

Note that even some databases that support window functions do not support `count(distinct)`.  However, some do.  The database you are using makes a big difference to this type of query.

As a note:  window functions are ANSI standard functionality, although not all databases support them.

EDIT:

Here is the trick for doing a `count(distinct)` on SQL Server:

```
select sum(case when empidrownum = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over () as TotalCount,
       dense_rank() over (order by empid) as RowNumber,
       row_number() over (order by empid) as RowNumber1,
       t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by empid order by empid) as empidrownum
      from table t
     ) t
```

Comment: SQL Server 2008 complains about using `distinct` with `over`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do, it will `GROUP BY` EmpCode and then will join to main record table, column order should be as in your example too.

```
select x.TotalCount, x.RowNum, ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
 (ORDER BY t.ID) AS RowNumber1, t.* from [table] t
inner join 
(select sum(*) as TotalCount, ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
 (ORDER BY EmpCode) AS RowNum, EmpCode from [table] 
group by EmpCode) as x on x.EmpCode = t.EmpCode
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select 
(select count(distinct empid) from yourtable) TotalCount,
dense_rank() over (order by empid) RowNum,
rank() over (order by id) RowNumber1,
*
from yourtable
```

This will work on SQL Server 2005 onwards, as well as on Oracle (not sure starting from which version).

Note that since SQL Server gives an error on using `distinct` with `over`, instead of a window function, I have used a subquery for getting `TotalCount`.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL-only solution

```
select count(distinct empid) as totalcount, 
       @empnum := case when @empnum <> empid then @empnum + 1 else @empnum end as rownum,
       @row := @row + 1 as rownumber1,
       *
from your_table
cross join (select @empnum := 0) e
cross join (select @row := 0) r
order by id
```